# Search value in tree of dicts in python

Tags: python, algorithm, search, dictionary, tree

I have a giant dict with a lot of nested dicts -- like a giant tree, and depth in unknown.

I need a function, something like `find_value()`, that takes **dict, value (as string)**, and returns **list of lists**, each one of them is "path" (sequential chain of keys from first key to key (or key value) with found value). If nothing found, returns empty list.

I wrote this code:

```
def find_value(dict, sought_value, current_path, result):   
    for key,value in dict.items():
        current_path.pop()
        current_path.append(key)
        if sought_value in key:
            result.append(current_path)
        if type(value) == type(''):
            if sought_value in value:
                result.append(current_path+[value])
        else:
            current_path.append(key) 
            result = find_value(value, sought_value, current_path, result)
    current_path.pop()
    return result
```

I call this function to test:

```
result = find_value(self.dump, sought_value, ['START_KEY_FOR_DELETE'], [])
if not len(result):
    print "forgive me, mylord, i'm afraid we didn't find him.."
elif len(result) == 1:
    print "bless gods, for all that we have one match, mylord!"
```

For some inexplicable reasons, my implementation of this function fails some of my tests. I started to debug and find out, that even if **current_path** prints correct things (it always does, I checked!), the result is inexplicably corrupted. Maybe it is because of recursion magic?

Can anyone help me with this problem? Maybe there is a simple solution for my tasks?

Comment: Why do you prefer non-recursive? Do you expect the tree depth to be so deep that you're afraid of a stack overflow?

Comment: @Gabe, I don't know. I'm just afraid of recursion in python. Max depth, i think, is 15-20, or even less. But it's unknown.

Also I'm afraid that recursion magic is thing, that might intercept me from debug the real problem.

Comment: Thing is that if your tree doesn't have some properties, you'll have to scan it all. IMHO your function is a bit overkill, because is recursive and it tries to emulate the recursivity with a stack. You should pick one :) See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831666/how-can-you-emulate-recursion-with-a-stack) for emulation

Comment: @equinoxel, ok, thank you, but forgive me, what would you really suggest me for my task? I assume you read all of my post? Also I don't worry to scan all tree if it havn't value :)

Comment: This should be recursive

Comment: @piokuc, if you say that, it will be. :) But what about realization? Is it well or even is it correct?

Comment: Do you want me to debug it for you or formally prove correctness?

Comment: A recursive solution to a recursive problem is always neater than a non-recursive one. After all, with the stack you're just emulating recursion ;)

Comment: @piokuc, debug for me would be my sweet dream, but I assume you have no time for that. Yes, I ask as junior for formally proving by experienced pythoner.

Comment: I don't know why but I don't feel like doing neither of these two things now. I can only give you one advice - open your eyes! recursion is cool! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `result.append(current_path)`, you're not copying `current_path`, which continues to mutate. Change it to `result.append(current_path[:])`.

Comment: I'll be damned. You find the bug!!!! Now it passes all the tests! You are just.. beautiful creation of God.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt you can do much to optimize a recursive search like that. Assuming there are many lookups on the same dictionary, and the dictionary doesn't change once loaded, then you can index it to get O(1) lookups...

```
def build_index(src, dest, path=[]):
    for k, v in src.iteritems():
        fk = path+[k]
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            build_index(v, dest, fk)
        else:
            try:
                dest[v].append(fk)
            except KeyError:
                dest[v] = [fk]

>>> data = {'foo': {'sub1': 'blah'}, 'bar': {'sub2': 'whatever'}, 'baz': 'blah'}
>>> index = {}
>>> build_index(data, index)
>>> index
{'blah': [['baz'], ['foo', 'sub1']], 'whatever': [['bar', 'sub2']]}
>>> index['blah']
[['baz'], ['foo', 'sub1']]
```

Comment: thank you, kind sir, I'll definitely use your idea if I need performance later :)