# Replacing recursion with while-loops and accumulators

Tags: java, swing, recursion

I'd like to calculate the height and set the resizeWeight of a JSplitPane that may contain other JSplitPanes and other Components as well. The concept right now looks the following (warning: snippet, not a fully functional code fragment; I only need guidelines for rewriting the recursive invocations with a while-loop using accumulators, not a fully functional solution code).

```
splitPane.setResizeWeight(calculateComponentHeight(splitPane.getTopComponent()) / calculateNewSplitPaneHeight(splitPane));
...
private double calculateNewSplitPaneHeight(JSplitPane sp) {
  return calculateComponentHeight(sp.getTopComponent()) + calculateComponentHeight(sp.getBottomComponent());
}

private double calculateComponentHeight(Component c) {
  if (c instanceof JSplitPane) {
    return calculateNewSplitPaneHeight((JSplitPane) c);
  }
  return (double) c.getHeight();
}
```

As I may not know the level of embeddedness of the split panes, what can be a practical approach towards resolving such recursions?

And yes, I know, `splitPane.getPreferredSize().height` and `splitPane.getTopComponent().getPreferredSize().height` give me the answers I need without *any* recursive invocations. This is question is merely here to work one's brain on recursions and loops.

Comment: Out of interest, why are you wanting to make this change?

Comment: Because I find converting recursions to loops fun. Yet I've found myself an interesting problem that looks like a double recursion and it keeps me thinking how such recursions can be resolved. I want to teach my brain to think in such way.

Answer (score 1):

You can emulate recursion with a stack: [How can you emulate recursion with a stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9831838/1851024)

I once made a try on emulating a simple Fibonacci-like recursion:

```
f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2) + array[n]
```

The result is [placed on a GitHub](https://github.com/chaschev/experiments-with-microbes/blob/master/src/main/java/stackoverflow/q18808144/RecursionEmuVsRecursionMicrobe.java#L219) and is written according to the explanations in the linked answer. I should admit that it was a more complex task than I first imagined.

Comment: Given an embeddedness of split panes large enough, won't the stack overload? That's why I've been thinking of an approach with accumulators.

Comment: Stack here is emulated - it's an `ArrayList` which is stored at heap. I'm quite sure that you may leave the recursionas you practically won't ever reach stack bottom in your example, which might be ~1000 embedded panes with a default stack size.